# How are Googles OTA (over the air) updates delivered/notified?

Tags: ota-update, 4.3-jelly-bean

I've got a Nexus 4 (but this question relates to all eligible devices) currently running Android 4.2. However Android 4.3 was announced a few days ago.

- I've run `Check for Updates`
- I've followed the tips to checkin <sup>†</sup>
- I've done the trick to "Force Stop" the *Google Service Framework* app and then pressed "Clear Cache".

But none of this seems to be doing anything, and I'm still running an "Up to date" OS with 4.2.2.

Is this a carrier issue? Could it be because I'm not on one of the [BIG THREE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Canadian_mobile_phone_companies) carriers in Canada (Rogers, Telus, Bell), but instead I'm on Virgin Mobile?

---

*footnotes:*

<sub>*†: `*#*#2432546#*#*` or `*#*#checkin#*#*`*</sub>

Comment: Perhaps Virgin Mobile are vetting the OTA?

Comment: When my WiFi Xoom was still officially supported, it took several (sometimes 30+) attempts at `Force Stopping` and `Cache Clearing` of `Google Service Framework` before `Check For Updates` would recognize I had an update.

Comment: From what I've read the force-stop of the Google Services Framework doesn't work any more.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have a WiFi Nexus 7 (so, no carrier encumbrance) and I didn't get the update until yesterday. They just seem to be rolling it out fairly slowly.

Comment: @AlEverett Same and I only got mine this morning. Still haven't received it for my Nexus 4. EDIT: Just the tried the answer to this and it worked for my Nexus 4, got 4.3 now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I tried to `"Clear Data"`, instead of just `"Clear Cache"` in the Google Service Framework (and Forced Stop).

I then ran the checkin again (Dial `*#*#2432546#*#*` in the phone app), and now I'm being shown the new `Android 4.3 System Update`.

Comment: Just tried this on my Nexus 4 and it worked (UK), I also force stopped GSF.

Comment: Worked for me too (China)

Comment: Worth noting that this can cause issues with the play store, if it does remove your primary account and re-add it.

Comment: Yes this seems to have removed my device from my Play Store devices. I've tried @jamesakadamingo's fix, but my device isn't there. Truthfully though, I'm just happy I have the latest version... Now trying the same thing with Keylime... er, KitKat.