# Do the ota use special command to reboot device

Tags: ota-update

Is it possible to update nexus device with OTA .zip file downloaded manually to /cache or /cache/fota_dn folder and reboot device ?

Or OTA update process use some special command to reboot device ? If so does anybody know which command is it ?

P.S. I know about the way to update device with bootloader like described [here](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/how-to-install-the-lollipop-ota-on-your-nexus-device-download-links-included/) but it is not what I'm asking about.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How does Over-the-air updates (OTA) work](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/65385/16575) / [How are Googles OTA (over the air) updates delivered/notified?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50225/16575) / [Manually upgrade Galaxy Nexus 4.0.4 (yakjuxw) to 4.1](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25977/16575) / [Where can I find the OTA update file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32205/16575) / our [ota-update tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ota-update/info)